# my string.Format c# error help me

Tags: c#, string.format

my code

```
 cmd.CommandText = string.Format("INSERT INTO cupom(Codigo, Moeda) VALUES ('{0}','{1}')",textBox2.Text);
```

print : [enter link description here](http://prntscr.com/7vwb7p)

help-me

Answer (score 1):

You need a second item for the second input. Like so

```
 cmd.CommandText = string.Format("INSERT INTO cupom(Codigo, Moeda) VALUES ('{0}','{1}')",textBox2.Text, textBox1.Text);
```

You have only 1 extra parameter when you need 2.

Comment: If you want to answer question that clearly should be duplicate than consider to provide all necessary information - like in this case explanation of SQL injection and proper handling of it in .Net

Comment: My Apologies. I will do better next time.